# Can we use piwik as a commercial Tool?

Tags: php, matomo

I am having a website which is a subscription based, i want to include piwik also into that website and sell that as service.

I have gone through some site but its still confusing whether to use it or not.

I am hosting piwik on my server and not selling it as software...

Comment: Piwik is GPL, I think you should search wether you can do that with GPL software you'll find more answers.

Answer (score 0):

As Piwik is available under the GNU General Public License, you are allowed to sell it as a service, however, any derived works of your implementation of Piwik can only be distributed under the same license terms.

In short, this implies that the source code of your implementation should be available when 'shipping' the product.

**More information about the GPL:**

https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License